linux kernel not sent packet in netfilter local out dnat
I want to implement DNAT in kernel but the packet is not be sent,and tcpdump could capture the SYNC TCP packet
1720173702.113934 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22049, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
10.28.149.204.45996 > 10.21.177.241.9999: Flags [S], cksum 0xd953 (incorrect -> 0x0032), seq 3410421434, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 550126439 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
1720173703.176781 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22050, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
10.28.149.204.45996 > 10.21.177.241.9999: Flags [S], cksum 0xd953 (incorrect -> 0xfc0a), seq 3410421434, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 550127502 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
1720173705.224726 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22051, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
10.28.149.204.45996 > 10.21.177.241.9999: Flags [S], cksum 0xd953 (incorrect -> 0xf40a), seq 3410421434, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 550129550 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
unsigned int hook(void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb,
                  const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
    __be16 real_protocol = ip_tunnel_parse_protocol(skb);
    if (!real_protocol || skb->protocol != real_protocol)
    {
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    }

    /* root is playing with raw sockets. */
    if (skb->len < sizeof(struct iphdr) ||
        ip_hdr(skb)->ihl * 4 < sizeof(struct iphdr))
        return NF_ACCEPT;

    struct nf_conn *ct;
    enum ip_conntrack_info ctinfo;
    unsigned int ret;
    int err;

    struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);
    struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *)((__u32 *)iph + iph->ihl);
    struct sock *sk = skb->sk;


    if (ip_hdr(skb)->daddr == LOOPBACK_ADDR)
    {
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    }


    if (iph->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
    {
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    }

    uint32_t subnet = in_aton("10.21.47.0");
    uint32_t netmask = in_aton("255.255.255.0");


    if ((subnet & netmask) != (iph->daddr & netmask))
    {
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    }

    iph->daddr = in_aton("10.21.177.241");
    tcph->dest = htons(9999);
    update_tcp_ip_checksum(skb, tcph, iph);

    err = ip_route_me_harder(state->net, state->sk, skb, RTN_UNSPEC);
    if (err < 0)
    {
        printk("cannot route harder\n");
    }

    printk("IP packet,source addr:%pI4,dst addr:%pI4\n", &iph->saddr,
           &iph->daddr);
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}

some one helps me,thanks a lot.
DNAT successfully,just like iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.21.18.14 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.28.149.204.
